# How to validate that Maven dependencies are compatible with Java 11

Tags: java, maven, java-11

I plan to migrate from Java 8 to Java 11, however since some JRE libs in 8 and 11 are not backward-compatible (there are lots of packages that were removed, see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320) it's hard to validate whether my dependencies are compatible with Java 11.

Imagine following pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <group>oldgroup</group>
  <artifact>oldartifact</artifact>
  <version>oldversion</version>
</dependency>
```

If this old dependency was compiled with Java 8 it can include imports from packages like `javax.xml.bind` that are no longer packaged with JRE 11.

It means that my project can **compile successfully with Java 11, but fail in runtime** with exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXB`.

Is there a way to perform validation during a build process (maven/gradle plugin?).

Comment: Why? Just add the JAXB dependency to pom

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera What if I someone else adds another maven dependency that was developed by another team that use Java 8? It will fail again. Of course, I can run jdeps tool, but there should be simple alternative. (I mean if there are multiple modules)

Comment: Just add the missing dependency. Java 11 was designed to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: It will fail in runtime until I add a dependency and that is not acceptable. (we have multiple small modules that run separately) Java 11 is backward compatible as a language, but the API can change.

Comment: [Migrate Maven projects to Java 11](https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/) contains a good list of things you need to consider/know... regarding possible outdated libraries... yes... that might be an issue, but I think with the given link it should be easier to solve your migration :-)